# SharedPreferences do not work anymore

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

The Shared Preferences in my app was working perfectly until I needed to free up some space on my device because I starting getting an Insufficient Storage message.  I therefore deleted some pictures from my device and uninstalled the app.  After reinstalling the app, my shared preference values are not retained upon reentry of the app.  In other words, after setting the shared preferences values in my Register Activity I finish the activity.  Upon re-entering the app, my saved boolean value is not retained and therefore restarts the Register Activity.  How is this possible without a code change?  I've read several with similiar issues but none assisted me with my situation.

Below is how I set my Shared Preferences code in my Register Activity:

```
isSaved = true;
//***Shared Preferences is merely storing values in area to be retrieved later

//Set up for the Shared Preferences     
String name = userName.getText().toString();
String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
//set the Shared Preferences, 0 is the default value
SharedPreferences userCreds = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_Creds,0);
Editor editor = userCreds.edit();
//editor.clear();
editor.putString("userName", name);
editor.putString("userEmail", email);
editor.putBoolean("Saved", isSaved);
editor.commit();
```

Below is the code that directs the app upon re-entry:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //May have to make a black screen for the transition here    
    //setContentView(R.layout.register_scrn);

    //Gets the isSaved value from Shared Preferences, if no value it will default to false
    getPrefFlag();  
    System.out.println("1st isSaved value: " + isSaved);

    //If the registration already exists, go to the recording and finish
    if (isSaved) {
        Intent comOnPatrol2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ComOnPatrol2.class);
        startActivity(comOnPatrol2);
        finish();
    }else{
        //Show Registration screen view and complete registration 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_scrn); 
    ...
```

Below is the getPrefFlag code:

```
private void getPrefFlag() {
    userCreds = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    isSaved = userCreds.getBoolean("Saved", false);
    System.out.println("isSaved after: " + isSaved);

}
```

Comment: Unless `PREFS_Creds` is your package name plus `_preferences`, you're using two different preference files. You need to consistently use either the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` method, or the `Context#getSharedPreferences()` method.

Comment: SharedPreferences work until you can not click clear data in setting of your phone.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first use `getSharedPreferences` with some name `PREFS_Creds`, and then use default preferences : `getDefaultSharedPreferences`. Unless PREFS_Creds is the same as default one, your error is because you use different preference files.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, you and Mike M were totally correct!  Thanks a mil!